# How to import Activiti process definition as sub-process into master process?

Tags: activiti, bpmn

We have created separate process definitions for review, approval and activate workflows (For `eg: review.bpmn, approval.bpmn, activate.bpmn`). I am creating a master process definition(`master.bpmn`) and want to import these three processes as sub-processes using Eclipse Activiti Designer.

How can I import them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "importing" the three process definitions you mean instantiating them in the course of executing the parent process?

-> In this case, in Activiti Designer Palette look for the "Call Activity" and move it into your parent process. When selected, in the tab "properties" of the call activity you will find an attribute "Called Element": This is the id of the separate process definition you want to call when your parent process runs into the Call Activity. In the Activiti User Guide you will find that here, including a visual example and an example of the underlying XML representation: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnCallActivity

Or did you mean with "importing" that you want to physically move your predefined process definiton elements into the parent process?

-> In this case, you can make of Activiti sub processes (http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnSubProcess) and directly embed the elements you used in your three pre-defined sub processes within an embedded sub process element. However, I am not aware of an Activiti Designer feature which would support a direct "import" of such elements into the process definition of your master.bpmn.

Comment: Importing diagram directly into sub-process is not possible in Eclipse Activiti Designer. I have created CallActivity elements for all my sub-processes and it not only solved my problem but also improved maintainability of my application. I am also able to independently test and deploy sub-processes independent of the master process.